# Python selenium can not find the click button

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, webdriverwait

I am trying this code to click on the javascript button. In the first frame you find the content, but when I place myself in the second html there is no menu.

How do I click on the button?

[image]

Code trials:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('frameset')
driver.switch_to_frame(1)
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')

print(driver.page_source)

driver.find_element_by_tag_name('frameset')
driver.switch_to_frame(1)
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')    

print(driver.page_source)
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    
    </head><frameset cols="170px,100%" framespacing="0" border="0" frameborder="0">
                    <frame scrolling="no" name="menu" id="menu" src="menu.jsp" />
                    <frame scrolling="yes" name="main" id="main" src="main.jsp" />
    </frameset>
```

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0):

As the the desired element is within an multiple `<iframe>`s so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the parent *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the child *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use the following solution:

  - Code Block:

    ```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//frame[contains(@src, 'login')]")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//frame[@id='menu' and @name='menu'][contains(@src, 'menu')]")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "squeda Avanzada"))).click()
    ```

> Here you can find a relevant discussion on [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)

Comment: Your locators are terrible and as I've mentioned before, the Selenium contributors have advised multiple times to avoid XPath when possible. Neither of your first two locators need to be XPath and for the second, there's no reason to use anything but `*_by_id('menu')`. It's simpler, better supported and there's nothing in the HTML to indicate that it won't work.